# List of where various algorithms/structures pop up in web development

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Could someone please list where some of the following algorithms/structures pop up in web development (I'm an aspiring web developer and I'm curious to know when these various topics pop up):

- Bubble sort
- Insertion sort
- Selection
  sort
- Mergesort
- Quicksort
- Stack
- Queue
- Linked List
- Binary Trees
- Binary Search Trees
- Balanced Binary Tree
- AVL Trees
- Splay Trees
- Red-Black trees
- Priority Queues
- Hashing
- Adjacency Linked Lists
- Adjacency matrices
- Graph
  Traversals (Depth First Search,
  Breadth First Search)
- Minimum
  Spanning Trees (Kruskal's algorithm,
  Prim's algorithm)
- Directed Graph
  (Digraph)
- Topological sort

The list is some topics that were covered in my Data Structures and Algorithms class. There might be some other important ones that I forgot to list as well.

Comment: Bubble sort only shows up in homework questions. Never in real world programming. Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, I already finished the course and decided to list all the topics covered. I am asking this question to get a better idea of how my knowledge is used in the real world for the field that I would like to go into.

Comment: Web development is a broad term.  If you encompass routing, scaling, etc. etc. you could very well include all of them, but if you're just writing a simple Rails app, you could get by with only a little algorithmic knowledge - anything more specific you could get at would help narrow it down.

Comment: @spinning_plate: You would never encounter some of these in the real world development (web or otherwise). eg. inferior sorting algorithms. They're taught in school to illustrate a point about performance but there's just no reason to use them ever when better options exist.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these are important for teaching concepts, and while some of them are commonly used in most applications (Stacks & Queues, e.g.), they don't really "pop up" the way you're describing.

It is important to understand the principles that these structures illustrate, and to know when to use a LinkedList vs an ArrayList. But as far as "when will I ever use this," it's awfully hard to point to a specific part of a website and say, "see, they used a binary search tree here."

Answer (score 1):

For most web development, these can be grouped together.

1. Quite a bit of web development is going to use a SQL back-end. In a `select` statement, you can have an `order by` clause what will undoubtedly be implemented by *one* of the sorts you've named (or something similar such as intro-sort, which is mostly a fairly minor variation on Quicksort).
2. Likewise, you'll deal with associative arrays, which are typically implemented as either some sort of hash table or some sort of balanced tree -- but could also use a splay tree.
3. graphs and graph traversal don't figure heavily in your typical (e.g., e-commerce) web development. For some types of network management, however, it's typical to put such things as servers into nodes of a graph, with arcs to signify the network connections.
4. Most languages you use will use stacks implicitly, but it'll be fairly unusual to use them explicitly in typical web development.
5. Queues will depend. You're not likely to implement a queue, but if (for example) you deal with a distributed database, you'll probably end up using some sort of queue that it provides.